# React Native PermissionsAndroid.check always returns true

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

According to the React Native docs `PermissionsAndroid.check` is supposed to return a boolean that shows if the corresponding permission has been granted, but for me this is always `true` independently of me enabling/disabling any permission for the app I'm building.

I didn't find any issue on the React Native Github about this, so I assume that this is a more of my issue than React Native's. What am I doing wrong/missunderstanding here?

System:

- React Native: 0.63
- Android Emulator: Pixel 4 API 29

Example:

```
async function checkPermissions(): void {
    const hasCameraPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA
    );
    const hasStoragePermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );

    console.log(`checkPermissions camera=${JSON.stringify(hasCameraPermission, null, 2)}, storage=${JSON.stringify(hasStoragePermission, null, 2)}`);
}
```

The result is always `checkPermissions camera=true, storage=true` independently of the app having permissions enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a wrong comparison , you should compare this

```
PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED === hasStoragePermission
PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED === hasStoragePermission
```

this will give you result that you have the permission or not

Cheers !!

Comment: No, that's not the case - the docs explicitely say that a Promise for a boolean is returned: "Returns a promise resolving to a boolean value as to whether the specified permissions has been granted.". Also, if I print the value it is a boolean that is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think these permissions has been filtered by google play

> Note: In some cases, the permissions that you request through  can affect how your application is filtered by Google Play.
>
> If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.
>
> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

Or the permission is no longer needed

> beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer necessary for your app to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

You can read the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element)

Comment: I don't think so - if I request the permission the prompt is shown. Also, I'm writing to the global Downloads directory, so I still need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.